# Randomization program: How to get data from a corresponding file based on the output of random.choice()?

Tags: python, random

I'm trying to make a simple program for my own personal use. It's a randomization program that I want to randomize both the Mastery (in this game's case, Grim Dawn, that's basically a class) and the Active Skill to level up and focus on using primarily. My goal with this program is to add some variety to the game by playing builds that I wouldn't regularly play due to them being randomly chosen for me.

Here's the first part of my program:

```
import random
import keyboard

print("Press enter to randomize your first mastery:")
while True:
    if keyboard.is_pressed("enter"):
        with open('masteries.txt', 'r') as f:
            masteries = f.readlines()
            random_mastery1 = random.choice(masteries)
            print(random_mastery1)
            break
```

This does exactly what I want it to do: Reads the game's classes from `masteries.txt` and outputs one of them randomly.

Next I have the following line of code:

```
print("Press enter to randomize your active skill for the {} mastery".format(random_mastery1))
```

What I want to happen is, based on the random Mastery that was selected from the `masteries.txt` file, it will then retrieve a random Active Skill from the corresponding Active Skill .txt file. For example, let's say that the randomly chosen Mastery was Soldier, I would like for it to choose an Active Skill randomly from the `soldieractiveskills.txt`file.

I've been researching on a decent way to do this, but I'm pretty stuck. It looks like there's a way to do this with variables, but I can't figure it out. Any input?

---

Update #1: Per Paul M's suggestion, here's what I have now:

```
import random
import keyboard

print("Press enter to randomize your first mastery:")
while True:
    if keyboard.is_pressed("enter"):
        with open("masteries.txt", "r") as f:
            masteries = f.readlines()
            random_mastery1 = random.choice(masteries)
            print(random_mastery1)
            break

file_name = random_mastery1.lower() + "_skills.txt"

print("Press enter to randomize your active skill for the {} mastery".format(random_mastery1))
while True:
    if keyboard.is_pressed("enter"):
        with open(file_name, "r") as skill_file:
            skills = skill_file.readlines
            random_skill = random.choice(skills)
            print(random_skill)
            break
```

However, I am getting the following when running the code:

```
Press enter to randomize your first mastery:
Oathkeeper

Press enter to randomize your active skill for the Oathkeeper mastery
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "c:\Users\xxx\xxx\Documents\Programming\Python\GrimRandom\randomizer.py", line 20, in <module>
    random_skill = random.choice(skills)
  File "C:\Users\xxx\xxx\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\random.py", line 288, in choice
    i = self._randbelow(len(seq))
    enter code here

TypeError: object of type 'builtin_function_or_method' has no len()
```

I have an `oathkeeper_skills.txt` file with contents in it, so I am unsure as to why this error is appearing.

---

Update #2: The above was fixed by adding the missing parenthesis from `skills = skill_file.readlines()`. The program is now working as intended.

Comment: If all your masteries and active skill files follow a strict naming convention, then you can get away with something like `file_name = random_mastery.lower() + "activeskills.txt"`.

Comment: So we are assigning the variable ```file_name``` as our ```random_mastery``` output and then adding ```activeskills.txt``` onto it in order to make, for example, ```soldieractiveskills.txt```? Makes sense, thanks. So now how do I fit that into my while loop here?

Comment: After creating the `file_name` variable, you would open the corresponding file using something like: `with open(file_name, "r") as skill_file:`. When the file is open you can read any content you want from it, just like you've done with the masteries file.

Comment: Paul, I have added an edit update to my OP on where I'm at now per your suggestion. I am new to Python so I am probably misconstruing your suggestion somehow which is causing that error.

Comment: It's all good! Thanks for editing your original post with the most recent changes / errors. Fortunately, it's a simple fix - you just forgot to add the paratheses `()` after `readlines`, so you'll just have to add them and the rest should work: `skills = skill_file.readlines()`

Comment: Yes, that worked!! Paul, you're awesome. Thanks for teaching me. I understand that this program could be accomplished in more many more efficient ways, such as using a .csv file to have two columns: ```Mastery``` and ```Active Skill```, but this way I understood better and feel it's "appropriate" for how simple the program is.

Comment: No worries, glad it's working!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217599/discussion-between-ajdbnabad13-and-paul-m).